# Relation between Rama and sita?

Tags: ramayana

If Nimi and Kukshi were sons of Ikshvaku then how could Rama and Sita marry? If they shared common ancestry then they would become brother and sister in relation, right? please elaborate.

Comment: See Ultimately all humans originated from Vaivasvata Manu only still they procreated. Anyway marriage between sapinda is forbidden i.e. seven generations on fathers side and also 5 generations on mother’s side. The line from Kukshi to Rama is way way way more than 7 generations, and so also between Nimi and Sitaji. Therefore marriage is allowed. Btw welcome to HSE

Comment: Hi, everyone in this world come from very few selected humans. Most of South East Asia has `lactose intolerance genetics`. It was all started by a human around 4000 years ago. In that respect, we all are brother and sister. We should not marry each other. There is a number of generation you have to wait before marrying into your way way way long before ancestors cousin family. It is logical & scientific. Also, Kukshi and Ram have a huge generation gap, & that is same for Nimi with Sita. They have more than 10 generation gap. Around thousands of years apart. They are not brother and sister.